# Java not continuing a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am making a simple for loop to go through an ArrayList and add objects to them but when I enter my first object nothing happens. It looks like the program isn't continuing the loop. Here is what I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (numPlayers.nextInt()-1); i++){
    System.out.println("what is player " + (i + 1) + " name?");
    Scanner namePlayer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerName = namePlayer.nextLine();
    playerList.add(new Player(playerName));
}
```

The player object constructor is very simple as well

```
public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. What is `numPlayers`?

Comment: Move `Scanner namePlayer = new Scanner(System.in);` out of the `for` loop

Comment: Whatever `numPlayers` is, it looks like it's providing a new value each time the loop iterates.  What's the second value you supplied it?  If that value is less than 2 then the loop will terminate as instructed.

Comment: every time you call `nextInt()` it reads a new int. I assume you meant to place `numPlayers.nextInt()` into a local variable so it is only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner numPlayers = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
        int input = numPlayers.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++){
            System.out.println("what is player " + (i + 1) + " name?");
            String playerName = numPlayers.next();
            playerList.add(new Player(playerName));
        }

    }
```

You should have declared `scanner` object outside the for the loop. The problem with your code was each time after taking a string input your code was needed to provide an integer for `(int i = 0; i < (numPlayers.nextInt()-1); i++)` and that's why if you provide anything but an integer it gives `InputMismatchException`. So you have to initialize the input constant outside the for loop otherwise execution will vary dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the limits of your loop only once, if possible:

```
int numberOfPlayers = numPlayers.nextInt()-1;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
    System.out.println("what is player " + (i + 1) + " name?");
    Scanner namePlayer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerName = namePlayer.nextLine();
    playerList.add(new Player(playerName));
}
```

You will need to make sure that you are iterating the loop as many times as you want.